# Flutter Stepper widget - conditionally hide a step

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to display the step 1 only if the api call returns true on the first step.

```
Stepper(
          currentStep: _currentStepper,
          onStepContinue: _continueStep,
          steps: [
            Step(
              title: const Text('Let\'s start with your phone number'),
              ***// call api***
            ),
            Step(***// this step should be displayed only if the first step returns true***
                title: const Text(
                    'Please enter the code sent to your mobile device'),
                content: OTP CODE Step
          ],
        ),


  void _continueStep() {
    if (_currentStepper == 0) {
      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        _signUpUser();
        _currentStepper = 1;
      }
    }
  }
```

UPDATE after applying MendelG's update.

@MendelG - the code you provided is not working for me. Here is how I implemented it.

A few things I noticed -

1. If I add a key to the Stepper widget then the input control inside the steps acts weirdly.
2. If I dont have the key added, then clicking on the continue button after the step will trigger an error.

Here is my code -

```
void _continueStep() {
    if (_currentStepper == 0) {
      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        print('Validated');
        GlobalVariables().cleanUserPhoneNumber(_phoneNumber);
        _signUpUser();
        isVisible = !isVisible;
        // _currentStepper = 1;
      }
    }
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _steps = [
      Step(
        title: const Text("Let\'s start with your phone number"),
        content: _intlPhoneFieldWidget(),
      ),
      Step(
        title: const Text("Please enter the code sent to your mobile device"),
        content: _otpCodeWidget(),
      )
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Stepper(
          currentStep: _currentStepper,
          onStepContinue: _continueStep,
          steps: isVisible
              ? _steps
              : [
                  Step(
                    title: const Text('Let\'s start with your phone number'),
                    content: _intlPhoneFieldWidget(),
                  )
                ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _intlPhoneFieldWidget() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const SizedBox(height: 50),
        SizedBox(
          child: IntlPhoneField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Phone Number',
            ),
            style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: GlobalVariables().textDisplayFont,
                fontSize: GlobalVariables().textDisplayFontSize),
            autofocus: true,
            initialCountryCode: 'CA',
            onChanged: (phone) {
              setState(() {
                _phoneNumber = (phone.completeNumber).trim();
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: is _signUpUser a future ?

Answer (score 0):

*Note: this isn't a tailored solution, you'll have to adapt this example to fit your needs.*

#### The problem

Usually, to show/hide widgets, you would use the [`Visibility`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html) widget.

However, here, the `Stepper` widget accepts a `List<Step>` so you can't use a `Visibility` widget.

#### Workaround

I've created a button to toggle the last step:

[image]

Create a list of `steps`, and add another widget based on a condition:

```dart
 final _steps = [
    Step(title: Text("step 1"), content: Text("content 1")),
    Step(title: Text("step 2"), content: Text("content 2")),
  ];
```

and within the `Stepper` widget:

```dart
 steps: isVisible
              ? [
                  ..._steps,
                  Step(title: Text("step 3"), content: Text("content 3"))
                ]
              : _steps,
```

Also, use a random `key` for the `Stepper` widget, otherwise, you'll receive [an error](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27187).

**Complete example**:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Test(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  var isVisible = false;
  final _steps = [
    const Step(title: Text("step 1"), content: Text("content 1")),
    const Step(title: Text("step 2"), content: Text("content 1")),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                isVisible = !isVisible;
              });
            },
            child: const Text("toggle the third step")),
        // show the steps
        Stepper(
          // use a random key
          key: Key(Random.secure().nextDouble().toString()),
          // i want to show 2 steps, but if the `isVisible` is true, i want to show 3 steps
          steps: isVisible
              ? [
                  ..._steps,
                  const Step(title: Text("step 3"), content: Text("content 3"))
                ]
              : _steps,
          currentStep: 0,
          onStepContinue: () {},
          onStepCancel: () {},
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be simpler to use a [collection-if](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators).

Comment: MendelG the code you provided is not working for me. I have added notes to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

How i would do it is to hide the 'continue' option until step 1 is finished. So:

```
          bool hideContinueOption = true;
        Stepper(
          currentStep: _currentStepper,
          steps: [
            Step(
              title: const Text('Let\'s start with your phone number'),
              ***// call api then if returns true, 
              //setState(() {
              //   hideContinueOption = false;
              //}*** 

            ),
            Step(
                title: const Text(
                    'Please enter the code sent to your mobile device'),
                content: OTP CODE Step
          ],
        ),


  void _continueStep() {
    if (_currentStepper == 0) {
      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        setState((){
          hideNextOption = true;
          _currentStepper = 1;
        };
        
      }
    }
  }
```

and instead of the `onStepContinue` parameter, you can do a custom one with `controlsBuilder`:

```
controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context, _) {
   return hideContinueOption 
     ? const SizedBox.shrink() 
     : Row(
        children: <Widget>[
         TextButton(
            onPressed: (){ _continueStep(); }
            child: Text('Continue'),
         ),
        ]
       ),
 }
```